# How do i increase my in memory Sort memory size from default 33554432 bytes to higher value in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I am getting error when I am executing a sort on non indexed field :
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 17144 and error message 'Executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33555047 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes' on server

I tried using 
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes:50151432}) { "was" : 33554432, "ok" : 1 }

When i use getParameter i can see the value set as 50151432

But i still see the error same with 33554432 with same size query.
Any ideas how to get over this

My Mongo version is 3.4

Comment: what is you sort query?

Comment: i have n number of fields I am using MongoTemplate in java to call the sort Query query = new Query();
   query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(field).is(value));
   query.with(new Sort(new Order(Direction.ASC, "type"))); All  values cannot be indexed.

Comment: how about adding index on the sort key?

Comment: I have few fields which are indexed. But i do not want to index all as the writes become too slow

Comment: Increasing the sort limit at server level to 50MB is likely to hit in future :)